# Animated svg loader

Tags: jquery, svg

I've got an animated svg page loader on this site http://www.potockipaterson.co.nz/ but the animation doesn't run until the page has actually loaded and the overlay fades out but obviously i want it to run immediately

```
    <script>
        $(window).load(function(){
            $('#loader').fadeOut('slow');
        });
    </script> 

    <div id="loader">
        <div class="greeting">
            <h1>WELCOME</h1>
            <p>one moment please....</p>
            <svg class="timer" version="1.1" id="L2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
              viewBox="0 0 100 100" enable-background="new 0 0 100 100" xml:space="preserve">
            <circle fill="none" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="4" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="50" cy="50" r="48"/>
            <line fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="4" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="50" y1="50" x2="85" y2="50.5">
              <animateTransform 
                   attributeName="transform" 
                   dur="2s"
                   type="rotate"
                   from="0 50 50"
                   to="360 50 50"
                   repeatCount="indefinite" />
            </line>
            <line fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="4" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="50" y1="50" x2="49.5" y2="74">
              <animateTransform 
                   attributeName="transform" 
                   dur="15s"
                   type="rotate"
                   from="0 50 50"
                   to="360 50 50"
                   repeatCount="indefinite" />
            </line>
            </svg>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: you may try saving the SVG as `.svg` file and include it in an `img` tag. Eventually you may need to put the `img` tag before the script

Comment: i initially had the script just before the closing body tag so it was coming after the svg . i then moved it above the svg under the notion that in order for the animation to run the script would need to load first but neither have worked . how would i go about saving the svg as a .svg file? after much googling i've not been able to find anything